# Problems with sec:autorize + thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I think I'm getting closer to the solution but still I'm stock on it. I change few things in the code. And this is the actual code:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="topMenu">
        <li th:each="menuItem : ${@mainMenu.getMenuItems()}">
            <div>
                <a th:text="${menuItem.getLabel()}" th:href="${menuItem.getUrl()}" th:sec:authorize="${hasAnyRole(menuItem.getRoles())}"></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="topSubMenu" th:if="${menuItem.getSubItems()} != null">
                <li th:each="subMenu : ${menuItem.getSubItems()}" th:class="${subMenu.getSubItems()} !=null ? 'hpit-topCategory'">
                    <div>
                        <a th:text="${subMenu.getLabel()}" th:href="${subMenu.getUrl()}" style="display:block"></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="topSubMenu" th:if="${subMenu.getSubItems()} != null">
                        <li th:each="subCategory : ${subMenu.getSubItems()}">
                            <div>
                                <a th:text="${subCategory.getLabel()}" th:href="${subCategory.getUrl()}"></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I used a user like:

```
<user name="david-gh" password="p" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_BLAH" />
```

and other user:

```
<user name="david-gh2" password="p" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

the menu loading is:

```
<bean class="web.data.MenuItem">
    <constructor-arg value="Home" />
    <constructor-arg value="/" />
    <constructor-arg value="ROLE_USER" />
</bean>
<bean class="web.data.MenuItem">
    <constructor-arg value="Assessment" />
    <constructor-arg value="###" />
    <constructor-arg value="ROLE_BLAH" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="web.data.MenuItem">
                <constructor-arg value="New Assessment Request" />
                <constructor-arg value="/requestClient" />
                <constructor-arg value="ROLE_USER" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

So the behavior that should has is: with `David-gh` should see everything but with `david-gh2` shouldnt see assessments. For now I see both things so my guess is that the command line:

```
<a th:text="${menuItem.getLabel()}" th:href="${menuItem.getUrl()}" th:sec:authorize="${hasAnyRole(menuItem.getRoles())}"></a>
```

It isn't working correct because `th:sec:authorize="${hasAnyRole(menuItem.getRoles())}"` don't work as should be.

Someone can please give me a hand???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fix my own problem and the answer is that thymeleaf has a bug that don't process correct the information inside a class. For fix it I figure this solution:

```
<div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasAnyRole(''__${menuItem.getRoles()}__'')')}">
```

this is not really nice thing but work for now :)